# Definitions from topology

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory

I'm reading some papers on the unknotting problem in Knot theory and am running into some notation I don't know (my exposure to topology is minimal, but I have seen it in Analysis courses, Algebra, and just general reading). Suggestions on what to google to get a definition or the definitions themselves would be great. They are the following:

- For a link K, what is N(K)?
- For a disc D what is $\partial$D?
- What is cl(*) (It appeared in the context of a surface S embedded in a 3-manifold M and cutting M along S to create a compact manifold cl(M-N(S)))

These things come up in several papers when I'm reading about Haken's algorithm. For example in here:
http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lackenby/ekt11214.pdf

Comment: $\partial D$ is the boundary of $D$; $\operatorname{cl}A$ is the closure of the set $A$.

Comment: Thank you. Is N(K) not standard notation?

Comment: It might well be, but I don’t know any knot theory; the other two are found elsewhere in topology.

Comment: $N(K)$ is probably a tubular neighborhood of $K$.

Comment: $N(K)$ here, or $N(S)$, means a tubular neighborhood of the knot or surface. We frequently want to throw out the interior of a tubular neighborhood so that the 'exterior' we get is compact.

Comment: Thanks again. So much just solidified with these definitions.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the comments:

$N(K)$ is a [tubular neighborhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood) of your knot, or surface, respectively.

$\text{cl}(A)$ is the [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) of a set $A$.

$\partial D^2$ is the boundary circle of the disc $D^2$. Be careful: this is not the same as the notion of [boundary of a subset of a space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)), but rather is a special case of the notion of the [boundary of a manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary).